# How to overrite boostrap 5 style in nuxt js project?

Tags: nuxt.js, bootstrap-5

So I am using Bootstrap5 in my nuxt.js project and want to override some of the bootstrap styles like colors, padding, font-size, etc, how to do it?

I know you have to create a separate .css file, but i dont know where to place it and include it in a project

Comment: Bootstrap or vue-bootstrap? Did you checked the related documentation?

Comment: @kissu bootstrap 5 and not vue-boostrap

Comment: Depending on how you have setup your whole thing, you may probably add it in the same manner. Start from here IMO: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/